# Не видно переменную в class

Tags: php, функции, классы

```php
<?php

class logs
{
    var $path;

    public function addPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
        echo($this->path);
    }

    public function newLog($text)
    {
        $localDate = date('d:m:Y', time());
        $localTime = date('H:i:s', time());

        echo($this->path . ' non');

        $filePath    = $this->path . '/' . $localDate . '.log';
        $defaultText = "[$localTime] => $text";

        $file = fopen($filePath, 'a+');
        fwrite($file, $defaultText);
        fclose($file);
    }
}

?>
```

и происходит что-то странное.
В 1 function переденную path видно.

А во 2 function ее не видно.
Ее кобу-то не сушествует.

Возможно это конечно тз за того что я в нее передаю $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT] . '/groups/'.$groupId.'/logs';
И тип пути нельзя но я не знаю.

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libs/logs.php';
(new logs)->addPath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/groups/$groupId/logs');
```

```
Сервер вернул неправильный ответ: /storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/191062515/logs non<br /> <b>Warning</b>: fopen(/20:03:2020.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/libs/logs.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/libs/logs.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/libs/logs.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br /> fc975d32
```

Comment: echo это лишнее.

Comment: echo это я уже пвтался понять есть ди что-то лил нет.  И он выводит первый echo с путем. А во втором случае только non. Хотя должен путь non

Comment: а в каком порядке Вы вызываете ? где пример вызова ?

Comment: Сервер вернул неправильный ответ: /storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/191062515/logs non<br /> <b>Warning</b>: fopen(/20:03:2020.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/libs/logs.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/libs/logs.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/libs/logs.php</b> on line <b>25

Comment: require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libs/logs.php';
(new logs)->addPath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/groups/$groupId/logs

Comment: `. "/groups/$groupId/logs'` <--- разные апострофы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил сам.

Проблема была в том что я каждый раз обряшался к class как к новому классу.

(new class)->function из за чего у меня в новом классе нет так называемой переменной.

Вот ее и нет.

Проблему решил просто:

```
$logs = new logs;
$logs->addPath();
$logs->newLog();
```